# AzureML endpoint deploy to AKS, the export parameter, deprecated since v1.14,is no longer supported

Tags: azure-aks, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm trying to deploy a model in AzureML and publish it as a endpoint in a Azure Kubernetes environment. This action gives after some time the following error:

> {
> "code": "KubernetesError",
> "message": "Kubernetes error: Bad Request. Reason: {" kind ":" Status "," apiVersion ":" v1 "," metadata ":{}," status ":" Failure "," message ":" the export parameter, deprecated since v1.14,is no longer supported "," reason ":" BadRequest "," code ":400}"
> }

This Kubernetes change seems to be mentioned in: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.14.md#deprecations and I'm using Kubernetes 1.21.2

The code is based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-and-where?tabs=python#register-a-model-from-a-local-file-1 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-azure-kubernetes-service?tabs=python#deploy-to-aks

Here is the script:

```
from azureml.core import Workspace, Environment
from azureml.core import Environment
from azureml.core.model import InferenceConfig
import urllib.request
from azureml.core.model import Model
from azureml.core.webservice.aks import AksWebservice
from azureml.core.compute import ComputeTarget

ws=Workspace("xyz-subscription", "xyz-resourcegroup", "xyz-azure-ml-name")
env=Environment('example-env')

urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://aka.ms/bidaf-9-model", "model.onnx")

model = Model.register(ws, model_name="bidaf_onnx", model_path="./model.onnx")

dummy_inference_config = InferenceConfig(
    environment=env,
    source_directory="./source_dir",
    entry_script="./echo_score.py",
)

compute=ComputeTarget(ws, "k8s-example")

deployment_config=AksWebservice.deploy_configuration(
    autoscale_enabled=True, 
    cpu_cores=0.1, 
    memory_gb=0.5, 
    auth_enabled=True, 
    enable_app_insights=True, 
    max_request_wait_time=4000, 
    namespace="example-namespace") 

service = Model.deploy(
    ws,
    "examplemodel",
    [model],
    dummy_inference_config,
    deployment_config,
    compute,
    overwrite=True,
)
service.wait_for_deployment(show_output=True)

print(service.get_logs())
```

Does somebody knows what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I've contacted Microsoft about this. It has to do with the deprecation of the export parameter. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.19.md#deprecation This is fixed for AzureML towards AKS 1.20.7, but broken again in 1.21.2. They are working on a fix for and probably released in 3 weeks from now.

Answer (score 0):

I saw at the top of the second doc on deploying to AKS:

"Important

Currently, Azure machine learning does not support deploying models to AKS version 1.21.x"

It looks like the Kubernetes version you mentioned is not supported (1.21.2).

Comment: Yes that is correct, the document is updated a few days ago https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/commit/4daa559a06ad3952d214295e896385e7b03fb00a#diff-29f28794f8aa44a10c8210cba4804b5fd27f88f8900fac5489d220477a9b0920